# ggplot2 is slow - where is the bottleneck?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, delay, survival

I'm wondering why I'm getting a delay when plotting survival curves in ggplot2. I'm getting a delay of factor 3 compared to plot (see example below)

However, if the ggplot-chart is saved only, this delay is small (factor 2 to 3 longer compared to plot).

I know very well that this is an old issue (> 9 y), I googled extensive discussions about it, but I still am unable to solve it or to localize the delay problem.

If the ggplot-chart has to be displayed onscreen the delay is round about factor 3 to 4 compared to plot.

Where should I search? Any idea what causes the delay?

```
n = 100000;

time  = runif(n, min = 1, max = 10)
event = runif(n, min = 0, max = 1)

df = data.frame(time = time, event = event)
df$event = ifelse(df$event < .5, 0, 1);
head(df)

library(survival)
fit <- survfit(Surv(time, event) ~ 1, data = df)

st <- Sys.time()
    plot(fit)
Sys.time() - st
#.... getting a process duration of 0.3439 secs


library(ggplot2)
x = data.frame(surv = fit$surv, time = fit$time, lower = fit$lower, upper = fit$upper)

st <- Sys.time()
    g = ggplot(x, aes(y = surv, x = time)) + geom_step(size = .5)
    ggsave(plot = g, file = '/tmp/test.png', dpi = 300, device = 'png');
Sys.time() - st
#.... getting a process duration of 0.9424 secs


st <- Sys.time()
    ggplot(x, aes(y = surv, x = time)) + geom_step(size = .5) + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) sprintf('%.0f%%', x * 100))
Sys.time() - st
#.... getting a process duration of 1.268 secs
```

Comment: Does the speed difference really matter? Unrelated, but try the tictoc package for timing.

Comment: ggplot2 just does more complicated things than the base plot, which is great for flexibility, but it is just going to take a bit longer due to the overhead. In this example, `geom_step()` is taking quite a bit of time to deduplicate the data. If you swap it out for `geom_path()`, it should be ~2x as fast.

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 steps that have to happen in a ggplot creation:

1. Constructing the various ggproto objects into a ggplot object. This is fast.
2. Converting the ggplot object, which is like a recipe, into a `ggplot_built` object, which is like a full technical blueprint. This step applies all the necessary stats, transforms and mappings to convert data into graphical objects. Its speed is dependent on the amount of processing your data needs, so is dependent on the size of your data.
3. Converting a `ggplot_built` object into a table of graphical objects (a gtable) in the low-level `grid` language, ready for drawing. This step depends on the number of objects in your plot, so may be faster if your data is summarized (eg a histogram or heatmap), compared to plotting all points (eg a dense dot plot or a raster image)
4. Drawing the gtree. This is largely handled by the `grid` package. Its speed is somewhat dependent on the *type* of objects being drawn as well as how many of them there are.

For your example, we can use your timing method each step takes

```r
# 1) Create the ggplot object
st <- Sys.time()
p <- ggplot(x, aes(y = surv, x = time)) + geom_step(size = .5) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) sprintf('%.0f%%', x * 100))
Sys.time() - st
#> Time difference of 0.01622295 secs

# 2) Converting to a ggplot_built object
st <- Sys.time()
p <- ggplot_build(p)
Sys.time() - st
#> Time difference of 0.1523981 secs

# 3) Creating the gtable
st <- Sys.time()
p <- ggplot_gtable(p)
Sys.time() - st
#> Time difference of 1.841841 secs

# 4) Drawing the plot
st <- Sys.time()
grid::grid.draw(p)
Sys.time() - st
#> Time difference of 0.4114258 secs
```

[image]

We can see that most of the time here is taken up converting the `ggplot_built` object into a `gtable`. This will be true whether we are writing an image or drawing to screen. The final step of rendering the image is down to how efficient the graphics device is at converting grid objects to graphical output.

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Allan, thank you very much ... this makes things much clearer for me ... from your comments ... can I deduce any measures to speed ggplot up, e.g. pre-aggregation of a data table? ... on the other hand ... I'm experimenting with lattice and it seems we're getting a speedup of factor 20